Plot Hazard ratio, 95% CI with a continous variable
Can R generate some figure like this?
x-axis=age(continous), y-axis = hazard ratio for each count?
Our dataset: mydata, event=death, time to event=years, var=age, group=treatment(1) vs control(0)


Welcome to Cross Validated! This seems to be a question about a specific type of software instead of about statistical analysis, so it is likely to be closed as off-topic. Briefly, look at the documentation for the R survival package for how to do the analysis. Some find the survminer package to produce nicer plots, although it might sometimes make poor default choices about things like axis limits. The rms package is great, once you learn to use it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See if this post answers your question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152303/interpretation-of-the-hazard-ratio-in-a-spline-model-on-continuous-exposures

The smoothHR package can be used to generate such plots in R. Personally, I would prefer other type of plots for this situation, such as survival area plots or survival contour plots, as described in this article: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10392888/. These can be generated using the contsurvplot R package (https://robindenz1.github.io/contsurvplot/).
Note that I am the first author on this article, so I am definitly biased here.
